# Reading file data into cell array of character strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, file-io, cell-array

I'm new to matlab. I have files conatins list of string like:

```
ABCCD
HGAQ
VBSER
```

I need to read it into `cell array of character strings`.

I tried this code:

```
fid2 = fopen('C:\matlab\data\myfile.txt');
tline = fgetl(fid2);

while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid2);
end

fclose(fid2);
```

However, I didn't know how to convert the output to **cell array of character strings**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) does that for you:

```
>> x = importdata('file.txt');
x = 
    'ABCCD'
    'HGAQ'
    'VBSER'

>> whos x
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  x         3x1               364  cell
```